# WP Multisite child theme: get_template_directory_uri() seeks it's own subdirectory instead of directory of parent theme

Tags: multisite

I am using WP Multisite to create different language versions of the same site. I use subdirectories in this case.

Generally website has a custom theme and each language version uses this theme as a parent.

To get parent theme functionality I try to point its directory ( http://example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme ) from child themes' subdirectories. Using get_template_directory_uri() I receive the root folder of specific language ( http://example.com/en/wp-content/themes/mytheme - wich is a language subdirectory ) insted of the folder with parent theme.

How can I get a correct URI?

Comment: Is this causing a problem? http://example.com/en/wp-content/themes/mytheme will be pointing to the exact same place as http://example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme

Comment: @Jacob Peattie, thank you for your attention. It seams that no problems with that. I just worry because it's a client's site so I want to be sure there are no surprises in the future usage.

Comment: Ok. This is the normal behaviour, so there's nothing to worry about.

Comment: OK, thank you so much